# Can anyone suggest why a rest request is slow in Cypress when using cy.origin?

Tags: cypress, same-origin-policy

I have a test in Cypress that visits 2 urls. If I do something like:

```
describe('the test', () => {
  
  it('is part 1', () => {
    cy.visit('url1.com')
    // do stuff
  })
  it('is part 2', () => {
    cy.visit('url2.com')
    // do more stuff
  })
})
```

This works fine, except of course when using Cypress in open mode, I lose all snapshots and DOM info from part 1.
If I try:

```
describe('the test', () => {
 
 it('is part 1', () => {
   cy.visit('url1.com')
   // do stuff
 })
 it('is part 2', () => {
   cy.origin('url2.com', () => {
     cy.visit ('/')
     // do more stuff
   })
 })
})
```

Then obviously the DOM info and snapshots are maintained, but a button that is clicked at the end of part 2, triggers a rest request... and that doesn't seem to happen until about 60 seconds after the test has finished! I've even tried without the 2nd `it` block - ie, just have the cy.origin continue from the `// do stuff` - no difference.

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong with cy.origin (if I am!?), or why I am seeing this? Is there a bug in cy.origin? FWIW, I have `experimentalOriginDependencies: true` in my config.

TIA

Comment: Technically, you don't need `cy.origin()` if the two domains are in separate tests. What do you mean by "I lose all snapshots and DOM info from part 1"?

Comment: Agreed it's not needed - but if you run cypress in open mode, then when both tests have finished, you can look back over the steps of the 2nd test, and see the snapshots etc - ie, the state of the DOM at any one point... but you can't do the same for the first test.... Which can be frustrating when trying to debug...

Comment: But why is `cy.origin()` changing that? I don't see the reason why it should. Have you got a runnable example?

Comment: It's weird for sure - when I don't use cy.origin, every test that hits a new URL almost restarts Cypress - reinitialising things. cy.origin stops that.....

Unfortunately I can't provide an example...